# RubyMine cant select Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, windows, sdk, rubymine

[Selection of SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YQ4j.png)

[Apply button does nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgKE.png)

After clicking on the apply button in the second image, nothing happens. Ok doesnt work either. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

in cmd: ruby -v results in C:\Users\mriedeman>ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching branch, RubyMine was able to select the Ruby SDK as intepreter. I dont know why but after switching branch the problem was resolved.

Another suggestion is to remove the .idea folder after closing RubyMine. It will be recreated once you re-open the project inside IDE.

Comment: If that happens again, you may also try closing the project in IDE and removing .idea folder from its root (it will be recreated once you re-open the project inside IDE)